# DotNet Core: AWS Lambda Resolvers

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

AWS AppSync enables us to use AWS Lambda to resolve any GraphQL field. I followed the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html
But, I want an example code for the DotNet Core using C#.

Comment: Here is the best example code: https://www.codefari.com/2019/12/aws-appsync-with-lambda-resolver-for.html

Answer (score 1):

AppSync currently does not have that particular tutorial in .NET, we will take this feedback into consideration for future tutorials. In the interim, I suggest you search through the .NET SDK repo and/or file an issue with particular questions you have that are specific to .NET where the above tutorial in another language does not suffice.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues